# How to use IF and ELSE statement for MS query

Tags: vb.net

> **Databasename:** `PEMS`
>
> **Table name:** `AccountInfo`
>
> **columns:** `AccountID`, `SubscriberID`, `Location`,`Passwords`,`AccountStatus`

AccountStatus values inside are `'Activated'` and `'Deactivated'`

Accepts or rejects an accountID based on their AccountStatus.
Example: if an account has an AccountStatus of `'Deactivated'` it will prompt that `AccountID` is blocked.

AcctID  48 and AccountStatus Deactivated it will reject when attempting to log in

Comment: your question is not clear

Comment: Are you simply saying that you want to query the database from VB.NET code to find out whether `AccountStatus` is `Activated` or not for a particular `AccountID` value?  That's basic data access.  What have you tried already?  If you haven't tried anything then you shouldn't be asking a question here.  Learn about data access first, do what you think is required and, if it doesn't work, THEN ask us a question about what you've done wrong.  We help those who help themselves; we don;t do your thinking or research for you.